# Form textarea behavior for carriage return / new line

Tags: doctrine-orm, newline, symfony-2.1, carriage-return, postgresql-8.4

I'm working on a project with symfony2, doctrine2 and sonata admin bundle.

When i edit field of an entity in a textarea, it saves it in a postgres database with \r carriage return. This is a problem for me as i use this field with java applets and the format must be correct.

Here is an example that satisfy me :

```
 -ISIS-  02210509232D

  42 45  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     1.6288   -9.1522   -0.6175 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    -0.0179    1.3546    0.0193 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     0.4111   -6.3640    1.1717 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     1.3655   -6.8310    0.0373 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

And here is what i get when editing the field of an other one :

```
Mrv0541 01081315253D          \r
 \r
   9  8  0  0  0  0            999 V2000\r
    -0.0166    1.3706    0.0096 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\r
    -1.1791   -0.7076    0.0095 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\r
     1.1396   -0.6403   -0.0123 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\r
```

How can i be sure that the field i edit in a textarea will be in the correct format ? (I don't want these \r)

**EDIT:**

I checked with javascript on the form page and there is no carriage return at all in the text. I disabled the trim for the field in form.

**Where can i check if it is symfony2 or doctrine2 that play a role in saving this entity field with carriage return in place of newline character ?**